# What does below pointer syntax mean

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Does below code segments mean the same thing or each one has a different meaning

```
char *data = "blah";
char* data = "blah";
char * data = "blah";
```

Comment: All are same...

Comment: Yes. They all mean the same thing.

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any and all research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three are same. The only differences are,

- The position of the asterisk and the whitespace around them(which is done according to one's preference)
- The string literals `"blah"` *could* be stored in the same memory location or different locations. From the C11 standard,

  > **6.4.5 String literals**
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > 7. It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
  >      appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
  >      undefined.

Comment: I guess then it is only a programmer's preference and not at all related to the language.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are same

```
char *data = "blah";
char* data = "blah";
char * data = "blah";
char*data = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

All of them are same. They all mean, `data is a pointer to type char`. The `space` in between don't make any difference. IMHO, you should have googled/binged that up.

EDIT:: Copied from The Paramagnetic Croissant comment, I think it will help others:: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)